# Weird Parse Error on Uploaded File

Tags: errors

so I'm working on this theme on my localhost, and I just uploaded it to see if it'd work and I'm getting a weird parse error for these lines in my functions.php file. It works fine on my localhost though:

```
$next = isset($_POST['next']) ? $_POST['next'] : false;
$prev = isset($_POST['prev']) ? $_POST['prev'] : false;

$nexp = explode('=', explode('?', $next)[1])[1];
$pexp = explode('=', explode('?', $prev)[1])[1];
```

It says, unexpected '[' on the line starting with $nexp and $pexp. I'm a bit confused (and tired), and I don't really see what the problem with this line is, and why it would work on localhost but not on the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array dereference (accessing array item directly after function result) is only possible since PHP 5.4, I'm guessing your remote server is running a lower version.

Just use:

```
$varname_temp = explode( 'stuff' );
$varname = $varname_temp[1];
```

Also on a side note, it's always best to set your local to use the same PHP version as your remote server.

Kat

Comment: I thought it was something like this. Thanks so much, I really need to stay more up to date with PHP development.

Comment: No worries, I find it annoying too that shared hosting providers still have not updated their PHP versions. Grrr.. :)